# Short story where an abused girl's parents switch places with a photo

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The main character is a child whose parents suddenly feel the child's feelings & memories of abuse. The father is sexually aroused by abusing the child.  (Ick ick ick)

The child is always sad in photos, even though the family might be at an amusement park or otherwise on a nice vacation.  At the end, the parents are the sad ones in the photos.
Like they switched memories w/ the child.